# Having trouble with POST method Clockify API

Tags: curl, post, terminal

I am currently trying to use Clockify's API and when I input the following line in my terminal:

```
curl -H "content-type: application/json" -H "X-Api-Key: {yourAPIkey}" -d '{"client":{"name":"Very Big Company","wid":{workspaceId}}}' -X POST https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/clients/
```

I get the following message:

> {"timestamp":"2019-08-22T13:18:37.565+0000","status":404,"error":"Not
>   Found","message":"No message available","path":"/v1/clients/"}

Comment: I want to create a new client in clockify using a POST request, but unfortunately it doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

I get it to work by changing it to :

```
curl -H "content-type: application/json" -H "X-Api-Key: {yourAPIkey}" -d  '{"id":"5b1e52ff0cb8792ed75992c1","name":"Client","workspaceId":"5c0fe3290cl84304845dbf1f"}' -X POST https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/5c0fe3290cl84304845dbf1f/clients/
```